# determine P(X+Y < 3)

Tags: probability

Let X and Y be two jointly continuous random variables with joint probability density function:

$f(x,y)$ = $\frac{1}{25}$ $(5x+y)$       for  $0<x<1$ , $0<y<5$

Hello can someone help me to solve this problem ? im stuck to find the integral limit for x because it is between 0 to 1

Comment: draw the 1x5 rectangle and draw the line X+Y=3. There are now two shapes. Your area to integrate over is the bottom shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you able to integrate $f(x,y)$ in the purple area?

[image]

$$\mathbb{P}[X+Y<3]=\int_0^1\Bigg[\int_0^{3-x}f_{XY}(x,y)dy\Bigg]dx$$